# Find image sequences in a directory - Quicker than os.walk()?

Tags: python, traversal

I am trying to write a script that will traverse a directory (pretty much the same as os.walk) but without using os.walk. The reason for this is that each directory is full of image sequences, and os.walk is taking way too much time.

My intention is to collect the filename of each image sequence... so currently, as soon as one singular image from a sequence has been found, I break out of the loop. This works fine if there is just 1 image sequence in a directory, but what if there are 2(or more) image sequences in a directory? This is where I am coming unstuck.

This is what I have so far:

```
def find_all_ImageSequences(dir):

    for object in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isdir(dir + "\\" + str(object)):
            find_all_ImageSequences(dir + "\\" + str(object))
        else:
            if object.endswith(('.dpx','.jpg','.jpeg','.exr','.tif')):
                Image_Sequences_List.append(dir + "\\" + str(object))
                image_filename = object.split(".")[0]
                extras = [x for x in os.listdir(dir) if x.split(".")[0] != image_filename]
                if extras:
                    "try to take the 1st image and add it to my Image_Sequences_List"
                break
```

The "extras" list comprehension will continue to look through every object in that directory, even after it's found a second image sequence. Is it possible to break out of this as soon as the 1st frame from the next image sequence has been found?

I thought about using:

```
if any([x for x in os.listdir(dir) if x.split(".")[0] != image_filename]):
    "do something"
```

But this seemed counter productive as I would then have to iterate through the current directory again to find the next sequence.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by image sequence? A set of files? How do you tell which files belong in the same sequence?

Comment: An image sequence in this instance, is a list of images(frames) from a movie clip. Each image in an image sequence shares the same name, for example; movie.001.jpg, movie.002.jpg, movie.003.jpg. Another image sequence would look like; holiday.001.jpg, holiday.002.jpg etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little tweaking this is what I found to be the quickest solution.

```
def find_all_ImageSequences(dir):

    child_directories = [x for x in os.listdir(dir) if len(x.split(".")) == 1]
    if len(child_directories) >= 1:
        for directory in child_directories:
            if os.path.isdir(dir + "\\" + directory):
                find_all_ImageSequences(dir + "\\" + directory)

    for object in os.listdir(dir):
        if object.endswith(('.dpx','.jpg','.jpeg','.exr','.tif')):
            image_filename = object.split(".")[0]
            Image_Sequences_List.append(dir + "\\" + str(object))
            if any([x for x in os.listdir(dir) if x.split(".")[0] != image_filename and len(x.split(".")) > 1]):
                extras = set([x.split(".")[0] for x in os.listdir(dir) if x.split(".")[0] != image_filename])
                for i in extras:
                    Image_Sequences_List.append(i)
            break
```

I did a quick test comparing this function to a standard os.walk():

- os.walk() took 53 seconds on average
- find_all_ImageSequences() took 5 seconds on average

The speed from this is primarily down to breaking out of the directory if no other image sequences are found. Thanks to Janne Karila for the help. Using a set() proved very useful

Answer (score 2):

This code uses a set to keep track of file names that were added already:

```
def find_all_ImageSequences(dir):
    seen = set()
    for object in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isdir(dir + "\\" + str(object)):
            find_all_ImageSequences(dir + "\\" + str(object))
        else:
            if object.endswith(('.dpx','.jpg','.jpeg','.exr','.tif')):
                image_filename = object.split(".", 1)[0]
                if image_filename not in seen:
                    Image_Sequences_List.append(dir + "\\" + str(object))
                    seen.add(image_filename)
```

---

To improve performance, check out https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir that has an `os.walk` replacement that is claimed to be about 8-9 times as fast on Windows, and about 2-3 times as fast on Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: I like this, but does it still not check every image in the sequence? I would like to, if possible, quickly find 1 image, then break out of that directory, unless there is another image sequence to find. So maybe I could use the any() statement I have in my example in conjunction with this. what do you think?

Comment: @iGwok If you don't know in advance how many sequences there are in a directory, you *have to* check all file names. Maybe the last one is a single-frame sequence.

Comment: I understand, I was hoping that there might be a quicker solution to doing this than iterating over every image file. For example using list comprehension seems quicker than using a for loop, and the any() statement I have seems farily quick at analyzing what's in the directory. Is there anything else which could help speed this up. Speed is the key here. thanks

Comment: @iGwok Most time is spent in retrieving the directory info from the OS. See my last edit for a possible improvement in that area.